# Do Input Builder attributes in MVC Contrib support localization?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, internationalization, data-annotations, mvccontrib

With Data Annotations for example, besides decorating members like this:

```
[Required(
    ErrorMessage = "You must enter your first name."
)]
public int FirstName { get; set; }
```

I can also do it like this to accommodate multiple cultures:

```
[Required(
    ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Customer),
    ErrorMessageResourceName = "NameRequired"
)]
public int FirstName { get; set; }
```

Does anybody know if the input builders in MVC Contrib support something like this for setting labels?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVC 2 do you have an attribute called `DisplayName`. `DisplayNameAttribute` doesn't support localization out of the box, but you can derived it and implement it yourself.

Here is an example how to do that: http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html

Comment: Thankfully the new DisplayAttribute class in .NET 4's DataAnnotations namespace takes care of this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.resourcetype(VS.100).aspx). Cool article BTW.